# How to calculate the percentage of a column against the SUM of all columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an sql query where I want to calculate the percentage of a column again the sum of all value in that column.

The table originally looks like this

```
Id |  name   |  score
----------------------
1  |  sam    |  15    
2  |  emma   |  20    
3  |  boyle  |  50    
4  |  edward |  90
```

The result should look like this

```
Id |  name   |  score  | percentage 
------------------------------------
1  |  sam    |  15     |   8.57%
2  |  emma   |  20     |   11.43%
3  |  boyle  |  50     |   28.57%
4  |  edward |  90     |   51.43%
```

..

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.  I prefer a simple ratio:

```
select id, name, score,
       (score * 1.0 / sum(score) over ()) as ratio
from t;
```

Multiply by `100.0` for a percentage.